# Flask: How do I get the returned value from a function that uses @app.route decorator?

Tags: python, oauth, flask, return

So I'm pretty new to Flask and I'm trying to make my mind around one thing. So, if I understand well when you write a function within a Flask app and you use the @app.route decorator in that function, it only runs when you hit that path/url.

I have a small oauth app written in Flask that goes through all the authorization flow and then it return the token.

My question is how do I get that token from the @decorated function? For example, lets say I have something like this:

```
@app.route(/token/)
def getToken(code): #code from the callback url.
    #/Stuff to get the Token/
    #/**********************/
    return token
```

If I hit the (/token/) url-path the function returns the token. But now I need to get that token and use it in another function to write and read from the API I just got the token from. My initial thought was doing this:

```
token = getToken(code)
```

But if I do that, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

So again, my question is, how do I get the token so I can pass it as a parameter to other functions.

Comment: You didn't show us all your code then; your `getToken()` function uses something that requires a valid request.

Comment: `getToken()` is **just** a function, all `@app.route()` does is register it with Flask so it can be found when the `/token/` route is requested.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But does that means that if I need to use the same function for showing something in the client/browser (e.g: showing the token to the user) and simultaneously access the API under the hood, I need to call the function twice? Isn't this redudant and inefficient?

Comment: I don't know. How 'heavy' is the token generation process? Can it be cached? If not heavy, don't worry, premature optimisation is the root of all wasted time.

Answer (score 3):

Extract the token generation code into a separate function, so that you can call it from anywhere, including the view function. It's a good practice to keep the application logic away from the view, and it also helps with unit testing.

I assume your route includes a placeholder for code, which you skipped:

```
def generateToken(code):
    #/Stuff to get the Token/
    #/**********************/
    return token

@app.route('/token/<string:code>')
def getToken(code):
    return generateToken(code)
```

Just keep in mind that `generateToken` shouldn't depend on the `request` object. If you need any request data (e.g. HTTP header), you should pass it explicitly in arguments. Otherwise you will get the "working outside of request context" exception you mentioned.

It is possible to call request-dependent views directly, but you need to mock the request object, which is a bit tricky. Read [the request context documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/reqcontext/) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the context is. You could just call the method.

```
from yourmodule import get_token

def yourmethod():
  token = get_token()
```

Otherwise, you could use the `requests` library in order to retrieve the data from the route

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('www.yoursite.com/yourroute/')
>>> print response.text
```

If you're looking for unittests, Flask comes with a mock [client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/)

```
def test_get_token():
  resp = self.app.get('/yourroute')
  # do something with resp.data
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I tried to do a GET against the route from which I want to retrieve the returnb value but I'm getting this: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'" Any idea? Best.